# history.replaceState() doesn't trigger a popstate event in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser-history, html5-history

I have a SPA / web app which accesses a REST API. The first request to the server returns a shell, and all subsequent requests are AJAX calls, which return JSON data, which is then rendered on the client.

For all direct routes (i.e. bookmarks / links / direct navigation) history.replaceState() is used (called within an onload handler). When back / forward navigation is then used, it works as expected in Safari / a popstate event occurs. In Firefox (60.0.2) however, no popstate event occurs. The state object is created and maintains the correct state as you navigate backward / forward, but the popstate event never occurs. The popstate event is correctly called when history.pushState() is used though.

Firefox is also caching the page state (i.e. backward / forward navigation still triggers a page refresh, even though the page is rendered client-side, and the AJAX and render functions (that are supposed to be triggered by popstate) are never called). I tried playing around with the Cache-Control header to no effect. I'm not sure if the Firefox cache could be causing some sort of conflict with popstate, but figure it's worth mentioning.

What exactly is going on here? Is there a known issue / bug with history.replaceState() in Firefox? I searched and couldn't find anything on history.replaceState() / everything I find pertains to history.pushState(). Or am I misunderstanding something?

Thanks

Comment: interestingly, the [MDN reference on the `popstate` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/popstate_event) states that neither should fire an event (`pushState()`/`replaceState()`).